# Xcode shows limited language list in Info.plist Localizations settings

Tags: ios, xcode

My project is created with Cordova and imported to Xcode 8.1.

I am attempting to localize the camera and photo roll permission reason values in Info.plist. The languages I am supporting are English and Swedish. I have a file called InfoPlist.strings, which has an English and a Swedish translation:

**InfoPlist.strings showing English and Swedish translation files**

[image: Screen Shot]

Some descriptions of the process for this also specify that I should add an entry to the Info.plist file called "Localizations", with the languages I want to support as entries. However, Xcode doesn't give Swedish an option when I attempt to do this:

**List of localization options showing a short list of possible languages**

[image: screen Shot]

Currently, the localization does not work. The value presented to the user is in English regardless of the devices language settings:

[image: Screen Shot]

How can I add Swedish to the list of supported localizations in the Info.plist file? Is there anything else do I need to do to make sure these strings will localize correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can just edit the info.plist file with your favourite text editor:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>sv</string>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>fr</string>
</array>
```